# How to perform a date conversion of following type

Tags: java, java.util.date

How to `convert` in `java` a string of format `2009/01` to a string of format `2009 January`?

Comment: have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), may help you..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
String date = "2009/01";
String format = "yyyy/mm";
Date dateObj = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date);
String newFormat = "yyyy MMM";
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(newFormat).format(dateObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM").parse("2009/01");
String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMMM").format(date);
System.out.println(format);
```